# Проблема с модулем в drupal 7

Tags: drupal, jquery

Устанавливаю модуль Views Isotope - jQuery Isotope(https://drupal.org/project/views_isotope) для сортировки материалов по тегам,все устанавливается хорошо, но не работает почему то. Когда заходишь в представление, то там такая ошибка

Warning: file_get_contents(/jquery.isotope.min.js) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in _locale_parse_js_file() (line 1488 of Q:\home\localhost\www\portfolio\includes\locale.inc).

Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

файл jquery.isotope.min.js должен лежать в sites/all/libraries/jquery.isotope/

Comment: sites/all/libraries/jquery.isotope/ создал такой каталог

там нет такого файла jquery.isotope.min.js

может его как то отсюда взять http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: в модуле же есть файл readme -  там есть ссылка на библиотеку и описание где она должна находиться